# Explanation of theorem/proof on dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Theorem: Suppose that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space wwith the ordered basis $\beta=\{x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_n\}.$ Let $\textbf{f}_i \, (1\leq i \leq n)$ be the $i$th coordinate function with respect to $\beta$ as just defined and let $\beta^* = \{\textbf{f}_1,\textbf{f}_2,\dots ,\textbf{f}_n\}$.  Then $\beta^*$ is an ordered basis for $V^*$, and, for any $\textbf{f} \in V^*$, we have

$$\textbf{f}=\sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{f}(x_i)\textbf{f}_i$$

Before I begin the proof I do not understand that very last line. So, I see that $\textbf{f}_i$ are the basis vectors so any vector in the space is a linear combination of the basis vectors but the coefficients $\textbf{f}(x_i)$ throw me off. If these could be explained that would be great.

Proof: Let $f\in V^*$. Since dim$(V^*)=n$, (I assume we are using this for linear independence?) we need only show that
$$\textbf{f}=\sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{f}(x_i)\textbf{f}_i$$

from which it follows that $\beta^*$ generates $V^*$, and hence is a basis. Let

$$\textbf{g}=\sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{f}(x_i)\textbf{f}_i$$
(^this feels like assuming the conclusion?)

For $1 \leq j \leq n$, we have

$$\textbf{g}(x_j)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{f}(x_i)\textbf{f}_i\right)(x_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{f}(x_i)\textbf{f}_i(x_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{f}(x_i)\delta_{ij}=\textbf{f}(x_j)$$

Therefore $\textbf{f}=\textbf{g}$.

I believe the above line but as I noted it feels like we have assumed the conclusion. Where is my thinking going wrong and what is the intuition here?

See related question here

[Dual basis existence and uniqueness.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383534/dual-basis-existence-and-uniqueness)

Answer (score 2):

It's right of you to be concerned. Let ${\bf x} \in V$ with ${\bf x} = (\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$. Write ${\bf x} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \alpha_i {\bf e}_i$, where ${\bf e}_i$ are the standard coordinates. Then for an element ${\bf f} \in V^\ast$, we have

$$
{\bf f}({\bf x}) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \alpha_i\, {\bf f}({\bf e}_i)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^n {\bf f}_i({\bf x}) {\bf f}({\bf e}_i)
$$

So, it seems they have written ${\bf f}(x_i)$ for ${\bf f}({\bf e}_i)$.