# Dual Space Subset Existence Proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces, hamel-basis

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. Let $V^*$ be the dual space of $V$. Choose a basis $ \mathcal{B} = \{\textbf{e}_1,\dots,\textbf{e}_n\}$ for $V$.

I would like to prove that there exist $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n \in V^*$ such that $$\textbf{v} = \theta_1 (\textbf{v}) \textbf{e}_1 + \dots + \theta_n (\textbf{v}) \textbf{e}_n$$ for some $\textbf{v} \in V$.

I am having trouble constructing such $\theta$'s, or finding a contradiction. This is a key stepping stone for proving that dual sets exist, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383534/dual-basis-existence-and-uniqueness). I do not see how this immediately follows from $\mathcal{B}$ being a basis of $V$.

Comment: The relation that you need, when you apply it to $v=e_i$ give you the values that the $\theta_i$ should take on a the basis $\{e_i\}$. Those values determine the linear functionals. In fact, the relation tells you that $e_i=\theta_1(e_i)e_1+...+\theta_n(e_i)e_n$. Since $\{e_i\}$ are a basis, then the coefficients from the right hand side must agree with the corresponding coefficients from the left hand side. So, $\theta_j(e_i)=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $\theta_i(e_i)=1$.

Comment: Yes, as soon as you define a linear function on the elements of a basis, then you have all the other values determined: If $v=a_1e_1+...+a_ne_n$, then $\theta_i(v)=\theta_i(a_1e_1+...+a_ne_n)=a_1\theta_i(e_1)+...+a_n\theta_i(e_n)=a_i$.

Comment: Ah, silly me. I thought that for some reason defining the linear functionals in that way raises concerns as to whether they remain linear functionals. Of course they are still linear functionals, they just have that special property.

Comment: You want $\mathbf{v} = \theta_1 (\mathbf{v}) \mathbf{e}_1 + \dots + \theta_n (\mathbf{v}) \mathbf{e}_n$ for ***all*** $\mathbf{v}\in V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the relation
$$
\mathbf{v} = \theta_1 (\mathbf{v}) \mathbf{e}_1 + \dots + \theta_n (\mathbf{v}) \mathbf{e}_n
$$
to hold *for all* $\mathbf{v}\in V$. In particular it should hold for $\mathbf{e}_1$, so
$$
\mathbf{e}_1 = \theta_1 (\mathbf{e}_1) \mathbf{e}_1 + \dots + \theta_n (\mathbf{e}_1) \mathbf{e}_n
$$
forces
$$
\theta_1(\mathbf{e}_1)=1,\quad
\theta_2(\mathbf{e}_1)=0,\quad
\dots,\quad
\theta_n(\mathbf{e}_1)=0,\quad
$$
Similarly, you get that
$$
\theta_i(\mathbf{e}_j)=\begin{cases}
1 & i=j \\[4px]
0 & i\ne j
\end{cases}
$$
Note that these relations are sufficient for defining linear maps $\theta_i\colon V\to F$, for $i=1,2,\dots,n$ (where $F$ is the base field), because we are prescribing their action on the elements of a basis.

Prove that, if $\mathbf{v}=\alpha_1\mathbf{e}_1+\alpha_2\mathbf{e}_2+\dots+\alpha_n\mathbf{e}_n$, then
$$
\theta_i(\mathbf{v})=\alpha_i
$$
and the rest should be easy.

Comment: Would it be valid to circumvent the relation and go straight to defining the $\theta_i(\textbf{e}_j) = \delta_{ij}$?

Comment: Then, could that be used to prove that the relation holds for some $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n$? How would one prove the relation otherwise?

Comment: @Leekboi This shows *why* you *must* define $\theta_i(\mathbf{e}_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Then it's just computing.

Answer (score 0):

To put the simple existing answer more concisely: Define $\theta_j$ by $$\theta_j(\alpha_1e_1+\dots+\alpha_ne_n)=\alpha_j.$$